# Changing a roofline for solar?

Tags: roof, solar-panels

Our 1950's built mid-century modern home faces roughly south, which is great for solar panels. However, thanks to its super cute low slope roof, with gables and hips galore, and lots of vents and pipes sticking out, our roof is 80% triangles that are barely big enough for a few panels each. Neighbors have installed solar panels on similar roofs, and it looks awful.

I can't shake this idea; where we just remove everything above the ceiling and replace the roof with a monoslope (flat) roof with parapets. There are nice mid-century designs with flat roofs, so I have hope that this could work out and not make our neighbors hate us or ruin our resale value. However, I'm pretty sure if I do it wrong we could end up looking like a strip mall convenience store.

I've looked at solar shingles, and its an option. They are a bit smaller than panels, so we would end up generating a bit more electricity than panels, and a lot less fugly. I don't think it would generate as many electrons than the mono-slope idea in the end, though.

My goal isn't saving money on electricity, it's reduction of emitted CO2e. This is part of a large Reno already being planned.

My question is; what professionals would you bring in? An architect and a roofing company? Plumber for the stack vents... what else?

Or, is this just a terrible idea? Why?

So, apologies in advance, this is DIY in spirit perhaps, though I'm unlikely to actually do all of the work. If there is a better site to try this question on I'm all ears.
[image]

Comment: That's a ***very expensive*** project. Whatever difference in output you get from the extra space gained will *almost certainly not pay off* the huge expense of replacing the entire roof structure (darn near half your house. May cost more as a retrofit than a teardown and whole new house.) Yard pole-mount trackers entirely separate from the house would be another approach. So contemplte the solar shingles if you like those better, and reconsider blowing huge sums of cash on changing your roof.

Comment: The idea of solar power is to save money.  Redoing the roof plus panels will probably cost too much, plus change the whole look of your house.  A ground based or solar shingles would probably be the best cost wise.

Comment: Also, from an insurance policy reference, if your roof is not recently replaced, do it before you place the panels. It's very expensive to replace a roof and have to pay for removal and reinstallation. Personal experience.

Comment: Mm, should have mentioned my goal isn't saving money on electrical, it's reduction of emitted CO2e. This is part of a large Reno already being planned...

Comment: This question is too broad and opinion-based for this site.

Comment: If we focus on the main question, "what professionals would you bring in?" this seems reasonable. Of course, the "is this a terrible idea" is going to be _entirely_ opinion based, so that part should be removed (especially since my opinion won't line up with the asker's).

Comment: Yes. It is a terrible idea.

Answer (score 1):

I would start with an architect. Get the design basics sorted, then start looking for a general contractor to redo the roof framing of the whole house.

If the GC doesn't do the roofing, plumbing, electrical, etc. let him deal with bringing in any subs necessary.

I'm not sure what the extra "e" in "emitted CO2e" is, but consider what CO2 you're emitting during the renovation (workers driving to the site, etc), bringing all the materials on-site, disposing of what's already there, making the solar panels, etc. i.e. Look at the *whole* picture - your payback period (emissions in addition to money) may be quite a bit longer than you envision.